# AdMob banner shows up after 60 seconds

Tags: android, admob

In the LogCat I see `Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.` message then after 1 minute the banner shows up when I start the app. Here is my code:

```
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, 2 * screenHeight - 75);

         // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Adding full screen container
        addContentView(adView, adParams);
```

How to make banner appear right after loading finished?

Comment: Hello,

why don't you declare your adView in xml ? 

Also, do you have adView.onResume() and adView.onPause() in onResume / onPause method of the activity ?

Comment: @Tristan hi, I am not familiar with Android development, I do cocos2d-x development. Hence I don't know where to create and XML file, what setting to set in eclipse and what to write in that XML. Hence, decided to go with no-xml. And yes, I have adView.onResume() and adView.onPause() in onResume / onPause method of the activity. But the problem is not with these methods, as far as banner appears with the delay on app startup.

Comment: Post the log before/after ```Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.``` There should be other info about ad display. Perhaps no ad was available initially.